# Angular ng-class with changing var

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

In my app i have a condition ng-class

```
 INDEX.HTML
 <div class="card-panel" ng-click="update(1)" ng-class="selectedPromotion == 1 ? 'blue accent-3' : ''">
     Cas 1
 </div>
 <div class="card-panel" ng-click="update(2)" ng-class="selectedPromotion == 2 ? 'blue accent-3' : ''">
     Cas 2
 </div>
 <div class="card-panel" ng-click="update(3)" ng-class="selectedPromotion == 3 ? 'blue accent-3' : ''">
     Cas 3
  </div>
```

The method update set the var choice

```
$scope.update = function(index){
    panierService.setChoice(index);
};
```

The method in my controller :

```
$scope.selectedPromotion =  panierService.getChoice();
```

But when i click on the different Div , the var is correctly set but the ng-class stay on the choice 1 , the method is not recall to apply the css Style

Any solution please ?

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is because the `$scope.selectedPromotion` does not have the same reference of the service's value (`panierService.getChoice()`), because they are numbers and not objects, and also the `panierService.setChoice` method possibly changes the reference (if it is an object). You can change the `$scope.selectedPromotion` from a number to a function that return the `panierService.getChoice`. And also, you can rename this variable as `$scope.getSelectedPromotion`.

```
 <div class="card-panel" ng-click="update(1)" ng-class="getSelectedPromotion() == 1 ? 'blue accent-3' : ''">
     Cas 1
 </div>

 <div class="card-panel" ng-click="update(2)" ng-class="getSelectedPromotion() == 2 ? 'blue accent-3' : ''">
     Cas 2
 </div>
 <div class="card-panel" ng-click="update(3)" ng-class="getSelectedPromotion() == 3 ? 'blue accent-3' : ''">
     Cas 3
 </div>
```

And in the controller you can do

```
$scope.getSelectedPromotion = function () {
   return panierService.getChoice();
};
```

The method `$scope.update` you can leave as you did.

Answer (score 0):

You've got to update your variable on change:

```
$scope.update = function(index){
    panierService.setChoice(index);
    $scope.selectedPromotion = index; //panierService.getChoice();
};
```

Comment: The problem here it is because you lose the consistency of the service value. Maybe the setChoice can make other logics than just set the index.